# Starling based 2d platformer having tilemaps larger then Max texture size

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I am working on a top down 2d platformer game in pure Starling for mobile (android/iOS) (no Citrus Engine). I am creating maps with tiled. Usually the maps are bigger then 2048X2048 and I am looking for a solution to this problem. There is a camera class which moves the map according to the player.
The technique that I have tried might be wrong as I am doing this for the first time. So please correct me if I am doing anything wrong and help me sort this out.

This is what I have done so far:

Map:

- created using tiled map editor
- there are multiple layers and the smallest size of the whole map is 2000x2000, tiles are 20x20
- for reading the tmx file I am using the Starling TMXMap extension (http://wiki.starling-framework.org/extensions/tmx_maps) (although I have made some tweaks to it)
  My approach :
- what I have done is I have created a render texture of screen size (1280x720 in my case) and was trying to draw the area of the map visible
- the TMXTileMap class creates sprites and stores them in an array... but instead of that I have added a function which takes the top-left co-ordinate and draws only the visible tiles on the texture

Problem : I am doing something terribly wrong here as the frame rate is dropping to 5-10fps. And also I am not able to properly move the map too.

I can post some code too if its required... if u can guide me in the right direction or help me out it would be great.

- these are the changes I have made to the TMXTileMap.as class of the extension that I have linked in the post.
- in the loadLayers() function at the end there is a call to drawLayers() method. I have commented out that method and added the below method which I am calling in a loop
- 'screen' is the texture (screen size 1280x720) on which I want to draw my map (larger then 2000x2000)
- 'screenRect' is the area of the map which I want to draw
- In order to understand it properly U might want to look at the extension class at http://wiki.starling-framework.org/extensions/tmx_maps

  ```
  public function drawMapLayers(screen:RenderTexture, screenRect:Rectangle):void
  {
      screen.drawBundled(function():void
          {
              for (var i:int = 0; i < _numLayers; i++)
              {
                  var col:int = Math.floor(screenRect.x / _tileWidth);
                  var row:int = Math.floor(screenRect.y / _tileHeight);
                  var endCol:int = Math.floor((screenRect.x + screenRect.width) / _tileWidth) - 1;
                  var endRow:int = Math.floor((screenRect.y + screenRect.height) / _tileHeight) - 1;

                  var initNum:uint = row * (endCol - col + 1) + col;
                  var lastNum:uint = endRow * (endCol - col + 1) + endCol;

                  //var initNum:uint = col * (endRow - row) + row;
                  //var lastNum:uint = endCol * (endRow - row) + endRow;

                  //trace("Points", col, row, endCol, endRow, initNum, lastNum);

                  for (var k:int = col; k <= endCol; k++)
                  {
                      for (var l:int = row; l <= endRow; l++)
                      {
                          var gridNum:uint = l * (_mapWidth) + k;

                          if (_layers[i].layerData[gridNum] != 0)
                          {
                              //trace(gridNum, _layers[i].layerData[gridNum]);

                              if (findTileWithGID(_layers[i].layerData[gridNum]) != null)
                              {
                                  var img:Image = new Image(findTileWithGID(_layers[i].layerData[gridNum]).texture);

                                  if (_layers[i].properties["alpha"] != undefined)
                                  {
                                      img.alpha = Number(_layers[i].properties["alpha"]);
                                  }

                                  if (img.width > _tileWidth || img.height > _tileHeight)
                                  {
                                      img.x = k * _tileWidth;
                                      img.y = l * _tileHeight;

                                      img.y -= (img.height - _tileHeight);
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                      img.x = k * _tileWidth;
                                      img.y = l * _tileHeight;
                                  }

                                  trace(gridNum, img.x, img.y);
                                  screen.draw(img);
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          });
  }
  ```

Comment: This is in ActionScript correct?

Comment: yeah... Starling is an AS3 framework...

Comment: I'm aware, you just didn't tag your question with it so I wasn't sure if you were using some kind of port I haven't heard of :-)

Comment: Anyway, did you use a TextureAtlas for all of your tiles? Using single different Textures for your graphics will destroy your frame rate.

Comment: The class that I am using for TileMap loading internally creates texture atlas for the tilesheets... and since I am drawing it on the render texture its happening in only one draw call.. so i dont think thats the problem... its the calculations thats happening for the drawing of tiles is causing the low fps...

Comment: I don't think some basic math for working with tiles on a grid would lower the FPS - maybe share some code so I can have a better look into it?

Comment: If you don't have the knowledge to build your own STage3D based background scroller you'll never get a good fps with Starling or any other framework out there. Scrolling background have to be done with a dedicated engine since that operation differs from a regular draw call. Pure UV mapping should be done with no matrix. Also you can't just load big multiple textures, you'll run out of memory and crash in no time. 2 is max. use seamless tiles so you can build a background with a smaller texture. If you can't do any of this then use classic display list, with good optimization you'll get 15 fps

Comment: @BotMaster : so what approach do u think i should follow ?? any abstract algorithm or anything that I can implement ??

Comment: Working with starling, create seamless tiles then build your background with them. Starling will be able to pull that off fps wise (one textureatlas). If you really want to have a bunch of original background scrolling then reduce their resolution (size) so you don't run out of memory. Also starling extensions often are experimental and do not guaranty performance. Finally building a small Stage3D engine to move texture based on UV only is not that hard.